# Remove texts inside a span containing other tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this span need to get rid og texts in side:

```
<span class="filter_column filter_date_range">From <input type="text" class="date_range_filter form-control" id="applicationList_range_from_6" rel="6" value="from"></input> to <input type="text" class="date_range_filter form-control" id="applicationList_range_to_6" rel="6" value="to"></input></span>
```

How can I remove text "from" and "to"?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add an example of this

Comment: Do you have to do this with jQuery? Can't you just remove this from the HTML?

Comment: I do sth like $('.filter_date_range').text(''); but this hide inputs as well

Comment: @Mivaweb nah, it is generated dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the text nodes out and then remove them:

```js
$('.filter_date_range').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3; // filter text nodes
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="filter_column filter_date_range">From <input type="text" class="date_range_filter form-control" id="applicationList_range_from_6" rel="6" value="from"></input> to <input type="text" class="date_range_filter form-control" id="applicationList_range_to_6" rel="6" value="to"></input></span>
```

The advantage of this approach is that any event handlers that were attached to the other elements aren't affected.